# How do i correct my DP solution for the Cherry Pickup problem

Tags: java

My approach seems to be correct , the issue is whether multiple trips are allowed.
My solution seems to exceed the correct answer.

**The Question:**

In a N x N grid representing a field of cherries, each cell is one of three possible integers.

0 means the cell is empty, so you can pass through;
1 means the cell contains a cherry, that you can pick up and pass through;
-1 means the cell contains a thorn that blocks your way.

Your task is to collect maximum number of cherries possible by following the rules below:

Starting at the position (0, 0) and reaching (N-1, N-1) by moving right or down through valid path cells (cells with value 0 or 1);
After reaching (N-1, N-1), returning to (0, 0) by moving left or up through valid path cells;
When passing through a path cell containing a cherry, you pick it up and the cell becomes an empty cell (0);
If there is no valid path between (0, 0) and (N-1, N-1), then no cherries can be collected.

**My Solution:**

```
class Solution {
    public int cherryPickup(int[][] grid) {

     int N = grid.length;

        int[][] dp;
        char[][] track;

        boolean f = true;

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while(f)
        {
            dp = new int[N][N];
            track = new char[N][N];

            dp[0][0] = grid[0][0];
            track[0][0] = 'a';

            char c;

            c='u';

            for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
            {
              if(c=='r'||grid[i][0]==-1)
              {
                  c='r';
                  dp[i][0]=-1;
              }
                else
                    dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + grid[i][0];

                track[i][0] = c;
            }

            c='s';

            for(int j=1;j<N;j++)
            {
                if(c=='r'||grid[0][j]==-1)
                {
                    c='r';
                    dp[0][j]=-1;
                }
                else
                    dp[0][j] = dp[0][j-1] + grid[0][j];

                track[0][j] = c;
            }

            for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
                for(int j=1;j<N;j++)
                {
                    if(grid[i][j]==-1||(track[i-1][j]=='r' && track[i][j-1]=='r'))
                    {
                        track[i][j] = 'r';
                        dp[i][j] = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(dp[i-1][j]>=dp[i][j-1])
                        {
                            track[i][j] = 'u';
                            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] + grid[i][j];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            track[i][j] = 's';
                            dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + grid[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }


            if(dp[N-1][N-1]<=0)
                break;

            sum += dp[N-1][N-1];

            int r = N-1 , cr = N-1;

            while(r>0||cr>0)
            {
                grid[r][cr]=0;
                if(track[r][cr]=='s')
                    cr--;
                else
                    r--;
            }

            grid[0][0] = 0;

        }

      return sum;
    }
}
```

Can someone help??